# Improve the flatten performance of this query

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Snowflake Community,

I'm running a Snowpipe that is continuously landing JSON into a staging table, which is then flattened into numerous target tables.

One of the destination tables requires running 4 lateral flattens on the JSON - something like this, but the data is loading faster than I can run the flattening.:

```
LATERAL FLATTEN(INPUT => JSON:data:Element) ELEMENT, 

LATERAL FLATTEN(INPUT => ELEMENT.VALUE) ATTRIBUTE, 

LATERAL FLATTEN(INPUT => ATTRIBUTE.VALUE) SUBATTRIBUTE, 

LATERAL FLATTEN(INPUT => SUBATTRIBUTE.VALUE) SUB_SUB_ATTRIBUTE
```

Would it be faster if I stored each flattened element in it's own table, then run the subsequent flatten statements on the upstream table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you considered a single recursive `FLATTEN()` to replace all the previous?

```
LATERAL FLATTEN(INPUT => JSON:data:Element, RECURSIVE => TRUE)
```